# RegOpenKeyEx Registry Security Result

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry, return-value

For the code below, I get no error however a non-zero return code, when trying to open HKLM\Security. The return code is 5 for `ResultC9` - ie Access is Denied.
The Key exists in the Registry (confirmed via Regedit). I read the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but that hasn't helped me. Please advise why I get "5" / "Access is denied" for `ResultC9`?

```
HKEY hKey5;

long resultC9 = ::RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SECURITY", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey5);
std::cout << "Value of GetLastError() is: " << GetLastError() << endl; // "0" is output to screen!      
std::wcout << "Value of resultC9 is: " << resultC9 << endl; // "5" is output to screen.
```

Comment: Presumably, you don't have the right access rights...

Comment: @MatsPetersson what access rights do I need for that key please?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I didn't write it as an answer. But I'm pretty sure the whole point of a special section in the Registry for "Security" keys is that you can't read them arbitrarily as a regular user.

Comment: You mayt want to just read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Note that according to the docs, `RegOpenKeyEx` returns its error code - you don't use `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I read the article (thank you) and tried using `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` as the value instead of `KEY_READ` - unfortunately this didn't work. Any hints please?

Comment: Have you used RegEdit to check the access rights actually are for this block? The point here is that I don't think your call is wrong, just that you are trying to use an interface in a way that requires more access rights than you have...

Comment: I have used MiniRegTool (by Farbar). Perms on key are:
DACL(PP):

NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM   FULL   ALLOW   (PI)(CI)

BUILTIN\Administrators   KEY_EXECUTE+KEY_READ+KEY_WRITE+READ_CONTROL+WRITE_DAC   ALLOW   (CI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told I need to take the `SeTcbPrivilege` privilege for this to work.